# Missing 3 required positional arguments error in flask even after I'm specifying them

Tags: python, html, flask

So I'm taking 3 inputs from the user, all are filepaths and then inputting them into a function that does its work. But I'm getting the above stated error everytime, where am I going wrong?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/info', methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def infotaking():
    if request.method == "POST":
        dp1 = request.form["dp"]
        mf1 = request.form["mf"]
        tess1 = request.form["tess"]
        #return redirect(url_for("user", pdflocation=dp))
        return redirect(url_for("aadharmask", pdflocation=dp1, masklocation=mf1, tessLocation=tess1))
    else:
        return render_template("infotaking.html")


@app.route('/masking')
def aadharmask(pdflocation, masklocation,tessLocation):
```

dp, mf and tess are being taken using infotaking.html

```
{% block title %} Input file paths {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action = "#" method = "POST">
    <p>datapath:</p>
    <p><input type ="text" name ="dp" /></p>
    <p>masked files saving path:</p>
    <p><input type ="text" name ="mf" /></p>
    <p>tesseract ocr location</p>
    <p><input type ="text" name ="tess" /></p>
    <p><input type ="submit" value ="submit" /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT**
After using @Parzival's solution a new error pops up, the Paths are being read wrong, I.E **what they should be**

- pdflocation: D:/dataset/pdf
- masklocaton: D:/dataset/masked
- tessLocation: D:/tesseract/tesseract.exe

**what they are**

- pdflocation: D
- masklocaton: dataset
- tessLocation:   pdf/D:/dataset/maskedD:/tesseract/tesseract.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@app.route('/masking/<path:pdflocation>/<path:masklocation>/<path:tesslocation>')
def aadharmask(pdflocation, masklocation,tessLocation):
```

You can also specify the data types if necessary:

```
<int:pdflocation>
```

The issue comes from the second app route, which you didn't specify how to generate the URL for masking.

```
@app.route('/masking') # No parameters are specified!
def aadharmask(pdflocation, masklocation,tessLocation):
```

Your function `aadharmask` expects three arguments (pdflocation, masklocation,tessLocation) from the url, but none were given. You need to specify how to create the URL using the given parameters - flask cannot generate a URL for a function with parameters unless specified.
[See Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules)

**EDIT**

It appears that you have the `/` character in the parameters, which flask interprets as another route. <s>Try replacing the `/` with `%2f` using</s>

Specify the `path` type in the URL, such as:

```
<path:pdflocation>
```

**New Option**

Try:

```html
<form action = "/masking" method = "POST">
    <p>datapath:</p>
    <p><input type ="text" name ="dp" /></p>
    <p>masked files saving path:</p>
    <p><input type ="text" name ="mf" /></p>
    <p>tesseract ocr location</p>
    <p><input type ="text" name ="tess" /></p>
    <p><input type ="submit" value ="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

```
@app.route('/masking')
def aadharmask():
    if request.method == "POST":
        dp1 = request.form["dp"]
        mf1 = request.form["mf"]
        tess1 = request.form["tess"]
        # process files if necessary
```

Comment: Alright, something worked, It redirected to the url but now I get an error "URL not found". I'm new to flask so I'm unable to figure out why

Comment: Ok, can you copy the url that was generated?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000/masking/D:/dataset/allpdf/big_pdf/D:/dataset/allpdf/masked_files/D:/Tess/tesseract.exe#          Here

Comment: The issue you're having is you have a `/` in the URL, which flask interprets as the second parameter. I'll edit the post and give it another try

Comment: But wont replacing it in the return function change the way the function in the second app route looks at it, anyway I tried the changes and get a StopIteration error

Comment: Ok i got it working, used the <path:D:/....> paramter,

Comment: Ah lol another stupid error now, its only reading the path upto "D:" and not reading the rest of path

Comment: Okay.. do you want to update the question?

Comment: Should I create a new question or update it with the new error?

Comment: Either way - I think it's just easier to update the question

Comment: I think this is still caused by the `/` delimiter. Can you try changing the delimiter to something like `&`? If that doesn't work, we'll have to go with replacing the slashes

Comment: Also, if you're only posting the request, you can directly set the form action to `/masking` and get the parameters there

Comment: Holy freaking hell it finally worked, thank you so much for your time man, the entire code's running perfectly now.

Comment: Your welcome! I'm glad it worked :)